# API Deployed with Python CDK Unable to Allow CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have a serverless stack deployed with the python CDK that is designed to allow a front-end test user to submit a file to an API Gateway which will then trigger a lambda function that writes it to S3.

The bucket is deployed to enable encryption and CORS:

```py
bucket = s3.Bucket(
            self, "UploadBucket",
            encryption=s3.BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
            removal_policy=cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
            cors=[
                s3.CorsRule(
                    allowed_headers=["*"],
                    allowed_methods=[s3.HttpMethods.PUT, s3.HttpMethods.POST, s3.HttpMethods.GET, s3.HttpMethods.DELETE],
                    allowed_origins=["*"]
                    )
                ]
            )
```

The API Gateway is deployed to allow CORS on POST requests:

```py
api = api_gw.RestApi(self, "file-api",
                rest_api_name="File REST Service",
                 default_cors_preflight_options=api_gw.CorsOptions(
                    allow_origins=api_gw.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
                    allow_methods=api_gw.Cors.ALL_METHODS,
                    allow_credentials=True,
                    allow_headers=api_gw.Cors.ALL_METHODS
            )
        )
        
        file = api.root.add_resource("{id}")
        
        post_file_integration = api_gw.LambdaIntegration(handler)
        
        file.add_method("POST", post_file_integration, 
                        method_responses=[{
          'statusCode': '200',
          'responseParameters': {
              'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': True,
          }}])
```

And the Lambda headers have been configured:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

const bucketName = process.env.BUCKET;

exports.main = async function(event, context) {
  try {
    var method = event.httpMethod;
    // Get name, if present
    var fileName = event.path.startsWith('/') ? event.path.substring(1) : event.path;

    if (method === "POST") {
      // POST /name
      // Return error if we do not have a name
      if (!fileName) {
        return {
          statusCode: 400,
          headers: {
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, OPTIONS, POST",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
          },
          body: "File name missing"
        };
      }

      const now = new Date();
      var data = fileName + " created: " + now;
      var base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');

      await S3.putObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: base64data,
        ContentType: 'application/json'
      }).promise();

      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, OPTIONS, POST",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(event.files)
      };
    }
    
    // We got something besides a GET, POST, or DELETE
  } catch(error) {
    var body = error.stack || JSON.stringify(error, null, 2);
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      headers: {},
      body: body
    }
  }
}
```

Yet my test user is unable to submit a file and receives the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked
```

Comment: First of all, specify your CORS configuration in one place, not in multiple places. Second, and although I'm not familiar with CORS configuration on API Gateway, you likely cannot use allow all origins, header, and methods in conjunction with credentialed requests as you're attempting to do here; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards.

Comment: Sorry could you please be more specific? At the moment the bucket, API Gateway and lambda func all have been passed the command to allow COR headers. Is there a recommended practise as to which should be passed this configuration?